# Including 3rd Party Modules in Angular App

Tags: angularjs

I would like to include a couple of 3rd party Angular modules in my App.  Previously I have only created simple apps that I simply use ng-app to bootstrap and put my code inside the controller.

From my understanding I should have something like this in my html:

```
<html ng-app"myApp">
```

Then my JS should look something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',['thirdPartyModule1','thirdPartyModule2']);

var myCtrl = function($scope, myApp, $http){

    //my stuff
};
```

But when I do this I get an error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: myAppProvider <- myApp
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to inject myApp into the controller. Your controller should be defined like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',['thirdPartyModule1','thirdPartyModule2']);

var myCtrl = function($scope, $http){
 //my stuff
});
```

to make it a little more "standard":

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['thirdPartyModule1','thirdPartyModule2']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  //my stuff
});
```

This way you can have a reference to your app if you like.

Now to make it compatible with minifiers/beautifiers/closure compiler:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['thirdPartyModule1','thirdPartyModule2']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
  //my stuff
}]);
```

That basically makes the controller argument an array, where the first members of the array are what you're going to inject. This is because a minifier will turn the arguments into random letters like `function(a,b)` and angular won't know what the heck you want to inject. By passing strings in the array thy will be minified like so `['$scope','$http', function(a,b)]` which is fine because the first two arguments in the array tell angular what to inject.

Comment: Thanks and` it's always good to learn best practices like that.  Now when I try to access functions in a third party module like this: thirdPartyFunction.doSomething I get a "thirdPartyFunction" not defined.

Comment: You don't access them like that. Angular modules provide services, directives, filters, etc. Once they've done that, you can just use them in your app. So if `thirdPartyModule` has a `FunTimes` service, you can just inject `FunTimes` like you do `$http`. Similarly, if thirdPartyModule has a filter, you just use it... `{{something | thirdpartyfilter}}`

Comment: Wonderful...thanks...step by step I am getting my head around this.

Comment: So how would you then call functions from thirdPartyModule1 in your controller?

Comment: @dumbledad if the module included a service, yes... inject that service and call functions from it.